# Order of the group $U(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that the order of the group $U(n)$ for $n>2$ is always an even number? If yes, how to go about proving it? U(n) is the set of positive integers less than n and co-prime to n ,which is a group under multiplication modulo.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What is your definition of U(n)?  Is the field **finite**?

Comment: The set of positive integers less than n and co-prime to n ,which is a group under multiplication modulo.

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3179674/edit) your question to include that important context, so readers know you're not talking about something else, such as unitary $n\times\n$ matrices

Answer (score 1):

The order of the group $U(n)$ is given by Euler's totient function $\phi(n).$

If $n=2^m$ then $\phi(n)=2^m-2^{m-1},$ which is even for $m>1 \;(i.e., n>2)$.

Otherwise $n$ has a factor of the form $p^m$ with $p$ an odd prime and $m\ge1$,

in which case $\phi(n)$ is a multiple of $p^m-p^{m-1}$,

so $\phi(n)$ is even since $p^m-p^{m-1}$ is (being the difference of two odd numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The order of the cyclic group $U(n)$ is $\phi(n)$, as there are $\phi(n)$ elements $ < n$ which are relatively prime with $n$(these are preciely the elements which possess an inverse in the cyclic group). And $\phi(n)$ addreses even values after $n \geq 2$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is in your group $U(n)$, then so is $n-x$, because any common divisor of $n$ and $n-x$ would also divide their difference $x$. So $U(n)$ has exactly as many elements $<\frac n2$ as it has $>\frac n2$. Since $\frac n2$ itself isn't in $U(n)$ (being a nontrivial divisor of $n$ --- this is where you use that $n>2$), the number of elements in $U(n)$ is double the number of elements of $U(n)$ that are $<\frac n2$. In particular, it's an even number.

In case you've already learned Lagrange's theorem, here's an alternative proof. $U(n)$ has an element of order $2$, namely $n-1$. By Lagrange, the order of any element in a group divides the order of the group. So $2$ divides the order of $U(n)$.

Comment: A possibly useful exercise: Understand why the two proofs in my answer are really the same proof.